# With InjectMocks, one of my mock become null, without it, an other Mock is null

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

So in this version, repository is null (and metric is not null) :

```
@Mock
OperationRepository repository;
@Mock
Metric metric;

SQLStrategy sqlStrategy;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    sqlStrategy = new SQLStrategy(metric);
}
```

In this version, metric is null (and repository is not null) :

```
@Mock
OperationRepository repository;
@Mock
ReneMetric reneMetric;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@InjectMocks
private SQLStrategy sqlStrategy = new SQLStrategy(reneMetric);
```

This is how they are defined in the class :

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component("sqlDb")
public class SQLStrategy extends StorageStrategy {

@Autowired
private OperationRepository repository;

private final Metric metric;
```

I was wondering what could be doing this behavior?

I can understand the need for *@InjectMocks* for repository to not be null since its an *@autowired* But I really dont understand why metric become null when I use *@InjectMocks*.

Comment: It might be due to the runner you are using. Each runner may have specified way of dealing with it

Comment: Does SQLStrategy have a default constructor? What annotations does it’s constructor have?

Answer (score 1):

First of all , `@InjectMocks` is a Mockito stuff and is nothing to do with Spring. It has no ideas about `@Autowired` and its existence will not affect `@InjectMocks` 's behaviour.

Normally you do not need to manually create the instance that you want to inject mocks into. If that instance has non no-arg constructor , Mockito will choose biggest constructors to create instance and inject the mocks through this constructor.

But in case the instance has a no-arg constructor or you instantiate it manually, Mockito will first use property setter injection , and then field injection to inject mocks.

And one caveat is that for the final field , field injection will not happen . You can refer to the [docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) for more information.

So change to the following should inject both mocks into `SQLStrategy` :

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SQLStrategyTest {
    
    @Mock
    OperationRepository repository;

    @Mock
    ReneMetric reneMetric;


    @InjectMocks
    private SQLStrategy sqlStrategy;


    @Test
    public void test(){
    }


}

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component("sqlDb")
public class SQLStrategy extends StorageStrategy {

    public SQLStrategy(OperationRepository repo , Metric metric){
        this.repo = repo;
        this.metric = metric;
    }
}
```

And the following explains why your example get such result :

1. You manually instantiate `SQLStrategy` . But at the moment when it is instantiated , Mockito still not create a `ReneMetric` mock , so `new SQLStrategy(null)` is called to create  `SQLStrategy`
2. Mockito create a mocked instance of `OperationRepository` and `ReneMetric`
3. Since you manually create `SQLStrategy` , Mockito will try to use property setter injection , and then field injection to inject the mocks into it. For the `OperationRepository` , it is injected because of the field injection. For the `Metric` , it is not injected because it is a final field and `SQLStrategy` does not have any setter for it.
4. So `OperationRepository` is not null and `Metric` is null